# State is not change on country onchange event

Tags: magento, checkout, billing

I have make custom drop-down for country and state. In this case, select box is create in html tags. Its working fine but onchange event is not working.

I have used this drop-down in billing information for onepage checkout process.

Please help me if you have good ideas about this.

I have used jQuery.selectbox.

Code show in below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').selectBox({
        mobile: true
    });
});
</script>

<select id="shipping:region_id" name="shipping[region_id]" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="custom-class1 custom-class2 dist-std validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you see any error in console?

Comment: No,error is not showing

Comment: Since it's a custom drop-down, it's impossible to help without the relevant html / javascript.  Please show your code.

Comment: I have edit my question with code